# Trouble with if statements

Tags: javascript

```
function lessThanNinety(num) {

//return true if num is less than ninety
//otherwise return false
//code here
}
```

Here is the problem, here is my solution.

```
function lessThanNinety(num) {
if (number < 90) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}

}
var number = 50;
```

Where am I going wrong? Thanks

Comment: The variable name is `num` and not `number`.

Comment: you are never calling the `lessThanNinety` function either

Comment: Better and short way. 
`function isLessThanNinety(number){ return number < 90 }`
`console.log(isLessThanNinety(50))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are using wrong variable name, change variable number to num:

```
function lessThanNinety(num) {
if (num < 90) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}

}
```

and you will need to call the function:

```
var number = 50;
lessThanNinety(number);
```

Comment: `return num < 90`